# If two cells match return a value from a third column to the same row where the cells matched

Tags: excel

I have three columns A, B, C.

Column A: 2,500 names
Column B: 150 Zones
Column C: 150 names associated with specific zones

What I want to is, if a name in column C matches a name in column A, the value that should be returned is the Zone that is associated with the name in column C that matched the name in column A, but this value should be returned in the same row (of a new column D) as the name that matched in column A.

For example, suppose that C2 matched A1000, so the value that should be returned is B2 to D1000

I've tried `=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C1,A:A,0))` but the value returned from this function is either not returned in the same row as A, or is returning the wrong value to the row that matched. What I want to is to return the value from B that is in the same row of the name of C that matched a name on A, but it has to be returned in the same row of A that matched.

Comment: What have you tried?  What result are you getting versus the one you expect?

Comment: Have you tried the `vlookup` function?  It should do what you need!

Comment: @OpiesDad  I've tried =INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C1,A:A,0)) but the value returned from this function is either not returned in the same row as A, or is returning the wrong value to the row that matched. What I want to is to return the value from B that is in the same row of the name of C that matched a name on A, but it has to be returned in the same row of A that matched.

Comment: I've edited into the question.  While most of the people answering questions could probably have figured out what you were looking for, this site is more to help people learn and solve specific issues than write code/functions for you.   By providing what you've tried, it allows them to pinpoint the issue you may be having.  I've answered with what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this backwards.

What you want is:

`=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A1,C:C,0))`

The `MATCH` function gives you the row in the specified range (second parameter to the function) that the searched item (first parameter) is.  So when you searched for `C1` in column A, you got the row in column A where the item in `C1` existed.  What you really wanted was the row in column C where the item in `A1` existed.